# Show multiple push notification in status bar in cordova android

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, ionic-framework

I am successfully implement the push notification in cordova [using this push plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin).

Everything works correctly, but the problem if multiple notifications are received only latest notification is available. I already referred [this answer](http://gonzalo123.com/2013/09/30/multiple-phonegap-push-notifications-in-the-androids-status-bar/), but it uses older plugin.

Here is the code what i tried from the answer.

```
int notId=0;
try {
  notId = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("notId"));
}
catch(NumberFormatException e) {
  Log.e(TAG, "Number format exception - Error parsing Notification ID: " + e.getMessage());
}
catch(Exception e) {
  Log.e(TAG, "Number format exception - Error parsing Notification ID" + e.getMessage());
}

notId++;
mNotificationManager.notify((String) appName, notId, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: notId always equal 0. So that it not show many notification. Declare notId outside as globle, it will working.

Comment: You mean declare as global class variable

Comment: Define notId outside createNotification function.

Comment: I tried but not worked

Comment: can you show an example code?

Comment: You must understand each notification(in Android) have a id. If you want show many notifications, you must make sure each notification have different id with others.

Answer (score 6):

The Phonegap PushPlugin separates multiple notifications by using the `notId` property of the notification as delivered from the GCM server.

What you need to do is make sure you generate the notifications with a ***unique*** `notId` property ***on your server***, when you send the notification to the GCM service (not on the phone!!!)

(The notId property is a property on the notification data object, just like `message` and `title`).

I also want to warn you that the current version of the plugin, v2.4.0, has a bug, so when the user clicks on the notifications, your app will still only be notified with the data from the latest. There is a patch for that problem here: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/pull/333

Comment: you saved me.. thanks buddy. I wish I can vote more than once on some answers