# When i receive puch notification , the new one is replacing the old one . How can i keep them both?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Sending notificaion from server :

```
 var req = {
     method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send',
     headers: {
        Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'key=xxxx' 
                          },

         data: { 
            "registration_ids": tokens,
            "data" :{
                    "title": "title", 
                    "body": "message"
             } 
     }
};
```

I am receiving the notification successfully , but when i'm sending another one , the new one is replacing the old one . is there any way to keep them both or collapse notifications ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change something in your application end not server side. e.g. If you use notification manager. Your code should be

```
yourNotificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(), yourNotificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: I'm using push Notification , not local notiication

Comment: Follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975558/show-multiple-push-notification-in-status-bar-in-cordova-android)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ionic/Cordoca and angularJS , here is my app code :

```
            var config = {
                    "senderID": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    'ecb': 'window.onNotification'
            };


                    $cordovaPush.register(config).then(function(result) {

                      // Success
                    }, function(err) {
                      // Error
                    })

     window.onNotification=function(e){
                    switch(  e.event )
                    {
                    case 'registered':
                        alert('registred');
                        break;

                    case 'message':
                        alert('just received a notification');
                        break;

                    case 'error':
                        alert('error');
                        return;

                    default:
                        return;
                  }
                }
```